# Lua more than one locals in one line

Tags: lua, local-variables

Assuming we have the following code:

```
local x = 1
local x, y = 2, 3
```

I know `x` will become 2 after the second line, however, does the local on the that line create a new `x`, or use the one before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be two different local values: the first one will be shadowed and not accessible as the second one is created with the same name in the same block. Here is the information that `luac -l -l` (Lua 5.3) shows for this script:

```
main <local.lua:0,0> (4 instructions at 00697ae8)
0+ params, 3 slots, 1 upvalue, 3 locals, 3 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADK       0 -1    ; 1
    2   [2] LOADK       1 -2    ; 2
    3   [2] LOADK       2 -3    ; 3
    4   [2] RETURN      0 1
constants (3) for 00697ae8:
    1   1
    2   2
    3   3
locals (3) for 00697ae8:
    0   x   2   5
    1   x   4   5
    2   y   4   5
upvalues (1) for 00697ae8:
    0   _ENV    1   0
```

The `locals` section shows three variables with two `x` that have the same end-of-scope location.

Comment: In other words, this is very bad design, simply overwrite the previous local in a situation like this.

Comment: This is very simple design, which has its advantages; I think this happens rare enough to worry about this case during language design.

Comment: I wasn't saying it was bad design on Lua's part, I meant on the coder's end. If this is how they overwrite their locals they're doing a really bad job.

Comment: @warspyking Overwriting isn't much of an improvement. You still end up with x meaning one thing at one point and something else later. With meaningful naming, one would rarely assign a variable twice.

Comment: @tom blodget Every little optimization counts, plus it's good to learn proper scripting practices.